# How can I neatly embed Flash in a page in a way that is cross-browser compatible?

Tags: html, flash

When I receive Flash objects from my designer, it comes with an example HTML page which includes both `<object>` tags and `<embed>` tags as well as a whole heap of JavaScript. If I copy and paste this code in to my webpage, it works, but the code looks a mess (and there is so much of it!). If I remove the extra code and try either just `<embed>` or `<object>` on their own, it works in some browsers, but not others.

Is there a neat, minimal method that works in all the major browsers?

Comment: Might want to try StackOverflow, better answers can be found there for this question.

Comment: Fair point - an SO search has revealed this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254027/which-browsers-support-the-embed-and-object-tags

However, I would imagine that most webmasters asking this questions would come here first, rather than StackOverflow, so I will self-answer with a link to the SO question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) is what you're looking for. It's a JavaScript library that does all the cross-browser heavy-lifting. Simply include the JavaScript file in your page, create an element to be replaced in your source, and tell swfobject the name that that element and the path to the `.swf` file.

It does the rest.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* path, replacement element, width, height, minimum flash version */
    swfobject.embedSWF("myContent.swf", "myContent", "300", "120", "9.0.0");
</script>
```

That's all you need. Well, that and an element (usually a `div`) with an `id="myContent"` on it. The element with that ID will be replaced with whatever embed tag setup your current browser prefers.

The [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation) is awesome, you'll have it up and running in no time. And if you hit any snags, ask another question.

Answer (score 4):

There are some great answers to this already over at StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254027/which-browsers-support-the-embed-and-object-tags

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at [Flash Satay](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/flashsatay/) - it is dated, but it quite nicely shows the issues in getting Flash working in a cross-browser fashion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the following resources:

[Flash Embedding Cage Match](http://alistapart.com/article/flashembedcagematch) - discusses the issues in detail and suggests some workarounds along with their pros and cons.

[swfobject library](https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) **[recommended]** - draws inspiration from the above article and adds functionality which the above article left as an exercise.

[SWFObject 2 HTML and JavaScript generator](http://www.bobbyvandersluis.com/swfobject/generator/index.html) - is a wizard which generates swfobject markup (HTML and JavaScript). You can ditch swfobject by choosing "static publishing", the remove all JavaScript tags from the generated markup.